# Alert dialog hides progress bar

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog, alert, box

I'm new to android studio and I have an issue that I can't solve. I searched for in the forum but did not find (or did not understand) a fix.

What I want: Ask user permission with a dialog alert box (YES/NO) for reading a csv file and when the user clicks yes, the dialog box is closed and the csv file is read with a progress bar.

What I get: When I click the YES button, the dialog alert box stays open, I don't see the progress bar because it is behind the alert dialog box. After reading the CSV file the alert dialog box is closed and  I did not see the progress bar at all.

here is the code :

```
private void AskUserConfirmation(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle("Fichier");
    builder.setMessage("Voulez vous ouvrir le fichier ?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OUI",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Read file
                    ReadCSVFile();

                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NON",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

I tried this :

```
        builder.setPositiveButton("OUI",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    //Read file
                    ReadCSVFile();

                }
            });
```

But the file is not read and the progress bar is not displayed.

So I tried this :

```
        builder.setPositiveButton("OUI",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Read file
                    ReadCSVFile();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
```

But the same issue, the file is read but the alert dialog box is not closed.

I need to close the alert dialog and then to read the file and then display the progress bar.

Any idea?
Thank you for your help!

Mika

Comment: try using dismiss()  before calling the ReadCSVFile()

Comment: Check what's inside `ReadCSVFile();`. Maybe something is blocking the Main UI Thread? Can you share the code? 
Try calling `ReadCSVFile();` outside Dialog and see if its blocking the UI.

Comment: @Viktor Jovanovski I removed the call to ReadCSVFile(); and the pb is still there. In fact, when the alert dialog box is opened and visible, any textview update makes the app crashing. It seems I can't update the GUI when the alert dialog box is opened and a few second after it has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `dialog.cancel()` with `dialog.dismiss()`.

Also, read the file before dismissing the dialog:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OUI",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Reading the file:
                ReadCSVFile();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention but I have already tried with dialog.dismiss(); and it is the same.

Comment: So I don't really get what's the problem exactly... Reading the csv file does work and the dialog closes right after that?

Comment: Yes the file is read but with the alert dialog box opened and then the progress bar is not visible. 

The alert dialog box is closed at the end of the reading, instead of when the user click 'YES'.

Comment: Is the progress bar visible before opening the dialog?

Comment: There might be a chance that AskUserConfirmation() called twice and 2 dialogs are shown. And when 1st dialog you click "Yes" it will dismiss and 2nd one would still be shown.

Comment: No it's not. I set the visibility when I start to read the CSV file, just when the user has clicked the 'yes' button. It seems that the display of the GUI is only updated when the alert dialog box is closed

Comment: AskUserConfirmation() is called once.

Comment: Is there a way to check when the alert dialog box has been closed ? I would call ReadCSVFile(); after this check.

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to `ReadCSVFile` in a thread. The way you have it written it is executing it on the UI thread and blocking dismissal of the dialog.

```
   builder.setPositiveButton("OUI",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.cancel();

                Runnable t = new Runnable()
                {    
                  @Override
                  public void run()
                  {    
                    ReadCSVFile();
                  }    
                };   
                new Thread(t).start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: It seems that the file is read after the dialog box is closed but I have to remove this : progressBar.setProgress(ProgressPercent); because the app crashes when it is called. So now the file is read after the dialog is closed but  i can't display the progressbar...

Comment: You never showed your `ReadCSV` code. Now that it's not in a UI-thread you can't call UI methods from a non-UI thread. I would either start an indeterminate spinner before you call `ReadCSVFile` so it shows work is being done, or I'd add a `MessageHandler` and post progress to it from inside `ReadCSV`

Comment: As I said, I'm new to java and Android and I did not understand what you wrote. I need time to learn spinner and MessageHandler. But if it can help, maybe my problem is that I update the progressbar in a for loop when I read the CSV file ? Is it possible to update textview or progressbar in a for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Dialog should be automatically closed when you click the positive button without write **dialog.dismiss()** or **dialog.cancel().**

Comment: Yes it is closed automatically but only after the file was read. I need to close it before the file reading.